# How do you find the URL to the SWF file using ActionScript 2?

Tags: url, flash, actionscript-2

I'm looking for a way to find out the URL of a SWF using ActionScript 2.

In ActionScript 3 this is done by using `root.loaderInfo.loaderURL`, but I haven't found any equivalent in ActionScript 2.

*Please note that I'm not looking for the URL to the page where the SWF is embedded, but the URL of the actual SWF, and that using ActionScript 3 is not an option (although I wish it were).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in every MovieClip is the _url property available.

example:
trace (_url);

Answer (score 3):

I found it myself:

```
_root._url;
```

Very simple!